# How to use scrapy Spider Middleware correctly?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a working `scrapy` project where I now want to add some custom Middleware.

I have enabled Spider Middlewares in `settings.py` by uncommenting the three lines below.

```
# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
   'sweden.middlewares.SwedenSpiderMiddleware': 543,
}
```

Nonetheless, any code I add to `middlewares.py` seems to be ignored. For example, the `input()` command I added to the last method below is not executed even though I successfully scrape some pages.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define here the models for your spider middleware
#
# See documentation in:
# http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

from scrapy import signals


class SwedenSpiderMiddleware(object):
    # Not all methods need to be defined. If a method is not defined,
    # scrapy acts as if the spider middleware does not modify the
    # passed objects.

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        # This method is used by Scrapy to create your spiders.
        s = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        return s

    def process_spider_input(self, response, spider):
        # Called for each response that goes through the spider
        # middleware and into the spider.

        input("press any key to continue")

        # Should return None or raise an exception.
        return None

   ...
```

I haven't modified the folder structure from the default. I couldn't make this work and examples seem to be lacking...

It doesn't show in the startup log either:

```
2017-08-21 16:59:41 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2017-08-21 16:59:41 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'FEED_URI': 'result.jl', 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'}
2017-08-21 16:59:41 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2017-08-21 16:59:41 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-08-21 16:59:41 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-08-21 16:59:41 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-08-21 16:59:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-08-21 16:59:41 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

This is the file structure:

```
.
├── venv
├── tutorial
└── sweden
    ├── __pycache__
    ├── scrapy.cfg
    └── sweden
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __pycache__
        ├── items.py
        ├── middlewares.py
        ├── pipelines.py
        ├── settings.py
        └── spiders
             ├── __init__.py
             ├── __pycache__
             └──  sweden_spider.py
```

Comment: Can you share Scrapy startup logs? does your middleware show up in `[scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:`? Does it change anything if you comment `crawler.signals.connect()`?

Comment: You are right, it doesn't show up under enabled middlewares in the startup log. Commenting `crawler.signals.connect()` doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Can you share the file structure of your project? (e.g. output of `tree`)

Comment: I have added the file structure.

Comment: Weird. If I do `startproject sometest ; cd sometest ; scrapy genspider example example.com` and then uncomment the generated `settings.py` around `SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES` and then run `scrapy crawl example`, I can see the spider middleware getting loaded and listed. Are you using `scrapy crawl`?

Comment: No, sorry, it's being run from a script using `process = CrawlerProcess(settings)` and then `process.crawl(SwedenSpider)` and `process.start()`.

Comment: So I guess it's about what's in `settings`: is this taken from `settings.py` or not (it may not be in your case)

Comment: Yes, good point!! Let me investigate. Thanks a lot for narrowing it down already.

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot for the help!! I was not looking at it from this angle at all. The settings were just a `dict` I defined instead of pulling it from `settings.py`.